# android 4 - Graphics with more than one thread

Tags: android, multithreading, graphics

I have a skelton of a drawing program, using one thread :

```
    @Override
public void surfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder) {
    pajeuThread = new PageThread( holder);
    pajeuThread.setRunning(true);
    Log.v(TAG, "surfaceCreated"  );
    pajeuThread.start();
} // end method surfaceCreated
```

Then I write "Hello World" near the center of the page, and I also write a number incremented by 30 down the left side of the page like this :

```
public void dessineArbre( Canvas canvasse ) {
    compteur += 30;
    if ( compteur > 500 ) compteur = 30;
    screenWidth = getWidth();
    screenHeight = getHeight();
    Log.v(TAG, "dessineArbre"  );
    pagePaint.setColor( Color.WHITE);
    canvasse.drawRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, pagePaint);
    pagePaint.setColor( Color.GREEN);
    canvasse.drawText( "Hello World", 200, 200, pagePaint);
    canvasse.drawText(Integer.toString( compteur ), 10, compteur, pagePaint);
} // end method dessineArbre
```

I would like the numbers drawn using a second thread.

The Thread is handled by an inner class this way:

```
        private class PageThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHoldere;
    private boolean threadIsRunning = true;

    public PageThread( SurfaceHolder holdere){
        surfaceHoldere = holdere;
        setName( "page thread");
    } // end constructor

    public void setRunning( boolean runninge)   {
        threadIsRunning = runninge;
    } // end setRunning

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvasvas = null;

        while( threadIsRunning ) {
            try {
                canvasvas = surfaceHoldere.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized( surfaceHoldere) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "PageThread try synchronized"  );
                    dessineArbre( canvasvas);
                }// end synchronized
            } // end try
            finally {
                if( canvasvas != null)
                    Log.v(TAG, "Pagethread finally"  );
                    surfaceHoldere.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvasvas);
            } // end finally
        } // end while
    } // end method run
} // end class Pagethread
```

How could I create another object of this class Pagethread?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to create a second thread and to get it to sleep for 1000 millis

```
    private PageThread pajeuThread;
private PageThread pajeuThread2;
    .
    .
@Override
public void surfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder) {
    pajeuThread = new PageThread( holder);
    pajeuThread.setRunning(true);
    pajeuThread2 = new PageThread( holder);
    pajeuThread2.setRunning(true);
    Log.v(TAG, "surfaceCreated"  );
    pajeuThread.start();
} // end method surfaceCreated
```

( I did not start() pajeuThread2 but it works anyway. )

```
public void dessineArbre( Canvas canvasse ) {
    screenWidth = getWidth();
    screenHeight = getHeight();
    Log.v(TAG, "dessineArbre"  );
    pagePaint.setColor( Color.WHITE);
    canvasse.drawRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, pagePaint);
    pagePaint.setColor( Color.GREEN);
    canvasse.drawText( "Hello World", 200, 200, pagePaint);
} // end method dessineArbre

public void drawCounter( Canvas canvassed ) {
    compteur += 30;
    if ( compteur > 500 ) compteur = 30;
    Log.v(TAG, "drawCounter"  );
    pagePaint.setColor( Color.GREEN);
    canvassed.drawText(Integer.toString( compteur ), 10, compteur, pagePaint);
    try{
       pajeuThread2.sleep( 1000);
    }
    catch( InterruptedException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "drawCounter exception"  );
    }

} // end method drawCounter
```

I added a call to the drawCounter method:

```
    private class PageThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHoldere;
    private boolean threadIsRunning = true;

    public PageThread( SurfaceHolder holdere){
        surfaceHoldere = holdere;
        setName( "page thread");
    } // end constructor

    public void setRunning( boolean runninge)   {
        threadIsRunning = runninge;
    } // end setRunning

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvasvas = null;

        while( threadIsRunning ) {
            try {
                canvasvas = surfaceHoldere.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized( surfaceHoldere) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "PageThread try synchronized"  );
                    dessineArbre( canvasvas);
                    drawCounter( canvasvas );
                }// end synchronized
            } // end try
            finally {
                if( canvasvas != null)
                    Log.v(TAG, "Pagethread finally"  );
                    surfaceHoldere.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvasvas);
            } // end finally
        } // end while
    } // end method run
} // end class Pagethread
```

This works fine but I am not sure if this is the proper way to manage threads.

Many thanks for your help